# empty tbody on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to empty all the rows inside the `tbody` on click of a new row. This is the javascript i am using:

```
$('#pro tr').click(function() {
    $('#pro_basket > tbody').empty();
        $.ajax({
            type: "post", url: "data.php", data: "index="+index,
            success: function(data) {
            $('#pro_basket > tbody').after(data);
        }
    });
});
```

My table markup is simple:

```
<table id='pro_basket'>
   <thead>
       <th>Column 1</th>
       <th>Column 2</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to empty the rows that exist in pro_basket but `$('#pro_basket > tbody').empty();` isn't really helping.

Comment: Do you have an error? Have you tried your code? What is your question?

Comment: I am not able to empty all the rows using ` $('#pro_basket > tbody').empty();`. That is what i want to achieve on each click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#pro_basket > tbody').html(data);
```

html() method will replace all exisitng elements in tbody

Your after() method would put new rows into table after the tbody which is not likely what you wanted

Comment: can you also add for plain javascript